# reading arbitrary numbers from file and bubble sort them

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

i'm trying to write a program that reads numbers from a text file( 21 12 44 21 -5 63 0 ) to an array and bubble sort them in an descending order, and printing out only positive numbers. i have been trying for a while but what is displayed is not what i expect.

the contents of the text file are:

```
21 12 44 21 -5 63 0
```

the full code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
class bubble
{
public:

unsigned* arr;
int n;

//Constructor
bubble(const int& size) : n(size) { this->arr = new unsigned[n]; }



//function to read from file
void inputvf(istream &f)
{
    //check if file is open

    if (f.fail()) {
        cout << "\n Error in openning file!!!";
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

        f >> arr[i];
        delete[] arr;
    //close file
    //f.close();
}



//Bubble sort function
void bubblesort()
{
    for (int i = 1; i<n; i++)//for n-1 passes
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<n - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] < arr[j + 1])
            {
                int temp;
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
void display()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "----------------------\n";
    cout << "Sorted array elements \n";
    cout << "----------------------\n";
    if (arr >= 0){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << arr[j] << endl;
    }
}
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
bubble list(7);
ifstream file("Text.txt");
list.inputvf(file);
list.bubblesort();
list.display();

_getch();
return 0;
```

results after i run the code:

```
4277075694
1
4261281277
2880154539
2880154539
4277075694
0
```

what am i doing wrong??? please help

this is the new code(below):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
class bubble
{
public:
//Array of integers to hold values
int* arr;

//Number of elements in array 
int n;

//Constructor
bubble(const int& size) : n(size) { this->arr = new int[n]; }



//function to read from file
void inputvf(istream &f)
{
    //check if file is open

    if (f.fail()) {
        cout << "\n Error in openning file!!!";
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

        f >> arr[i];
        //delete[] arr;
    //close file
    //f.close();
}



//Bubble sort function
void bubblesort()
{
    for (int i = 1; i<n; i++)//for n-1 passes
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<n - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] < arr[j + 1])
            {
                int temp;
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
void display()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "----------------------\n";
    cout << "Sorted array elements \n";
    cout << "----------------------\n";
    if (arr >= 0){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << arr[j] << endl;
    }
}
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
bubble list(7);
ifstream file("Text.txt");
list.inputvf(file);
list.bubblesort();
list.display();

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

In `inputvf`:

```
delete[] arr;
```

You should not delete the array at this point - you haven't even started using it yet.

This declaration:

```
unsigned* arr;
```

means that all of your input is `unsigned`, which means -1 is read as 4294967291 and thus will be treated as a large number. Change your array to a normal int and then use an if test to ignore negative numbers when outputting.

Comment: thanks, i have tried what you wrote but still it's wrong and now it's just large negative numbers.